# using dataset.addSeries with a Long[] values

Tags: java, arrays, double, jfreechart, long-integer

The arguments that dataset.addSeries takes are as follows `(java.lang.Comparable key,
             double[] values,
             int bins,
             double minimum,
             double maximum)`

Right now, I am trying to use a variable called `Long[] v1` in the `double[] values` field and cannot figure out how to convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Jon Skeet's answer on [How to convert array of floats to array of doubles in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019362/how-to-convert-array-of-floats-to-array-of-doubles-in-java/2019374#2019374), I quote:

> Basically *something* has to do the conversion of each value. There
>   isn't an implicit conversion between the two array types because the
>   code used to handle them after JITting would be different - they have
>   a different element size, and the long would need a conversion whereas
>   the double wouldn't. Compare this to array covariance for reference
>   types, where no conversions are required when reading the data (the
>   bit pattern is the same for a String reference as an Object reference,
>   for example) and the element size is the same for all reference types.
>
> In short, *something* will have to perform conversions in a loop. I
>   don't know of any built-in methods to do this. I'm sure they exist in
>   third party libraries somewhere, but unless you happen to be using one
>   of those libraries already, I'd just write your own method.

The following is an adapted implementation of Jon's answer to fit your question:

```
public static double[] convertLongsToDoubles(Long[] input)
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        return null; // Or throw an exception - your choice
    }
    double[] output = new double[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = input[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Plagiarized from this answer by Jon Skeet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2019374/19679 . If you're going to steal, I guess pull from the best.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to do this yourself.

Write a method that does the conversion for you.

```
public static double[] convertFromLongToDouble(Long[] l) {
double[] doubleArray = new double[l.length];
     // .. iterate through the Long array and populate to double array
return doubleArray;
}
```