# How to convert byte array to double array?

Tags: java

How to convert this byte array to double array.

```
byte[] byteArray = {1,0,0,1,0};
```

I like to convert this from not using a loop because this byte array have a bulk of elements.

Please help me

Comment: Why not use a loop?

Comment: With one `double` per `byte`? Just copying the value? Sounds like a good candidate for a loop to me...

Comment: @Kushan: so? as long as you don't need to manually step through that loop in your debugger that's not a problem. Computers are *good* at doing long loops ;-)

Comment: This will definitely require a loop on some level as each byte (two's complement representation) has to be physically converted to a double (floating point representation)

Comment: I for one am still waiting for a _satisfactory_ answer as to why loops "aren't allowed".

Comment: @user1571871 not neccessairly, iteration can less efficiently be implemented with recursion (see my answer)

Comment: @linski true but I would still categorize recursion as "a loop on some level". What I meant is that you can't just cast the array or something like that.

Comment: @user1571871 agree on both points ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Computing))

Comment: sounds like an exam/test question to me lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible "loopless" solutions would use [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) or [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28byte%5B%5D,%20int%29), but in these solutions you cannot avoid casting your `byte[]` to a `double[]`. The problem is this casting is impossible according to the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html):

> ```
> Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time reference 
> type T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time 
> errors occur due to the following rules.
> [...]
> If S is an array type SC[], that is, an array of components of type SC: 
> [...] 
>   - If T is an array type TC[], that is, an array of components of type TC, 
>     then a compile-time error occurs unless one of the following is true: 
>     - TC and SC are the same primitive type. 
>     - [...]
> ```

Use a loop. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019362/how-to-convert-array-of-floats-to-array-of-doubles-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there are some operation java not provide single line operations, since it is not actually needed.

Let's consider following. I am converting your byte array to String in single line with no loops.

```
    byte[] byteArray = {1,0,0,1,0};          
    String str=Arrays.toString(byteArray);
```

But,

Inside that `toString()` many things going on.

```
    public static String toString(byte[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";
    int iMax = a.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1)
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        b.append(a[i]);
        if (i == iMax)
            return b.append(']').toString();
        b.append(", ");
    }
}
```

Now you can see, actually there is a `loop` here. Similarly if you able to find a single line way to convert `byte[]` to `double[]` you are doing same thing.(with loops).

You can do this as follows

```
 byte[] byteArray = {1,0,0,1,0};
 double[] arr=toDoubleArray(byteArray);
```

But, you need following method too.

```
public static double[] toDoubleArray(byte[] byteArr){
    double[] arr=new double[byteArr.length];
    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        arr[i]=byteArr[i];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid loops, iteration can be implemented as recursion:

```
public static double[] convert(byte[] in, int idx) {
    double[] ret;
    if (idx == 0) {
        ret = new double[in.length];
        ret[0] = (double)in[0];
    }
    else {
        ret = convert(in, idx-1);
        ret[idx] = (double)in[idx];
    }
    return ret;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] byteArray = {1,0,0,1,0};        
    double[] converted = convert(byteArray, byteArray.length-1);
    for (int i=0;i<byteArray.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(Byte.toString(byteArray[i])+ " converted to double "+converted[i]);
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
1 converted to double 1.0
0 converted to double 0.0
0 converted to double 0.0
1 converted to double 1.0
0 converted to double 0.0
```

However:

- it is not clear from your question what are you trying to achieve but when converting from bytes to double you *must* be aware of that byte array [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Examples_of_storing_the_value_0A0B0C0Dh_in_memory)
- I wouldn't recommend replacing loops with recursive iteration because it has significantly more overhead
- if you want to cast the byte array to double array that cannot be done (see kol's answer)

Comment: as far as i know, recursion is a loop

Comment: that depends on the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Computing)

Answer (score -3):

I'm assuming that you're looking for a Java answer...

This will do what you want in a single line, but it still does looping in the background. As far as I know, there is not a way to cast an array without some degree of looping taking place somewhere

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asDoubleBuffer().array();
```

Comment: i want a double array not double value

Comment: changed the code sample, still has the problem of "technically" doing the loop somewhere

Comment: Still not really working `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: @scourge192 Well, if we're going to be technical about it, there's literally no way to do this without loops unless you manually want to do out[0]=(double)in[0]; out[1]=(double)in[1]; out[2]=(double)in[2]; for all 700,000 elements.

Comment: The buffer needs to be backed by an accessible array. You could use new double[buffer.remaining()] to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: @Smallhacker Yeah I know, that's what I was saying in my answer. He was looking for a way to do it without writing a loop so I gave it a shot XD

Comment: using `ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asDoubleBuffer().get(new double[bytes.length / 8]);` works, don't know why my edit I made was rejected